# Drupal Calendar Popup Theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

The following code is the default for the method theme_jcalendar_view which is a theme function.

```
<?php
    function theme_jcalendar_view($node) {
      $output = node_view($node, TRUE);
      $output .= '<div id="nodelink">'. l(t('more', array(), $node->language),         calendar_get_node_link($node)) .'</div>';
      return $output;
    }
?>
```

In my theme I want to output the full body of the node rather than the teaser? How would I do this? I think I add the method to my custom template.php file with the name myThemeName_theme_jcalendar_view.

Thanks

Linda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look at the api for [node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_view/6) the true is the teaser. So doing something like my code should work (not tested):

```
<?php
  function mytheme_jcalendar_view($node) {
```

return node_view($node); 
       } 
    ?>